# Is it possible to tell dynamically NLog which target to log to?

Tags: wpf, logging, nlog, unhandled-exception, first-chance-exception

I want to implement the `AppDomain.FirstChanceException` in my WPF app, for optionally logging every exception that occurs, handled or not. I don't wish to log these exceptions to the targets I have configured for NLog. Is is possible, around the time of calling `Logger.Error` (or whatever `Logger` method) to make NLog only log to one particular target?

Comment: Probably I misunderstood your question, but do you need to change your NLog targets in the `AppDomain.FirstChanceException` handler?

Comment: Quite right, @IlVic, I want that one Logger method call, e.g. `Error`, inside `AppDomain.FirstChanceException`, to only log to file, not to DB, nor memory.

Answer (score 6):

It's possible, but this is not a good idea because:

1. It's not thread safe.
2. All loggers of the specified factory will be reconfigured.

Configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <targets async="true">
    <target name="file1" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/log1.txt" />
    <target name="file2" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/log2.txt" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file1,file2" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Example of a global factory configuration:

```
var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

logger.Error("Original Configuration");

var configOrig = LogManager.Configuration;
var configTemp = LogManager.Configuration.Reload();
var rule = configTemp.LoggingRules.First(r => r.NameMatches("*"));
var target = configTemp.FindTargetByName("file2");

rule.Targets.Remove(target);

LogManager.Configuration = configTemp;
logger.Error("Temporary Configuration");

LogManager.Configuration = configOrig;
logger.Error("Original Configuration");
```

Example of a user created factory configuration:

```
var factory = new LogFactory(LogManager.Configuration);
var logger = factory.GetCurrentClassLogger();

logger.Error("Original Configuration");

var config = factory.Configuration;
var rule = config.LoggingRules.First(r => r.NameMatches("*"));
var target = config.FindTargetByName("file2");

rule.Targets.Remove(target);
factory.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
logger.Error("Temporary Configuration");

rule.Targets.Add(target);
factory.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
logger.Error("Original Configuration");
```

log1.txt

```
2015-03-16 21:46:04.5685|ERROR|ConsoleApplication.Program|Original Configuration
2015-03-16 21:46:04.5865|ERROR|ConsoleApplication.Program|Temporary Configuration
2015-03-16 21:46:04.5865|ERROR|ConsoleApplication.Program|Original Configuration
```

log2.txt

```
2015-03-16 21:45:26.4238|ERROR|ConsoleApplication.Program|Original Configuration
2015-03-16 21:45:26.4588|ERROR|ConsoleApplication.Program|Original Configuration
```

**Soulution**

The best solution of the problem is to create two factories and one logger for each factory. The factories and loggers must be initialized before you subscribe to `AppDomain.FirstChanceException`. Otherwise, you will have problems with thread safety if you have async operations or other threads.

Comment: @Yoh, thanks, some nice detail. So, it looks like I will need two `GetLogger` methods in my factory, and use one logger specifically for where I want more detail, and the other logger elsewhere. In other words, I can't actually do anything at the time of using the logger, only when creating it?

Comment: You need two factories and one logger for each factory. The first factory will use default configuration and the second - a modified configuration with some targets removed.